# Fusion layer marker style not set

Tags: google-fusion-tables

The attached screen shot is the FusionTablesLayerOptions object out of the Chrome debugger. Marker color management is "red" if not selected and "yellow" when selected.  the column "SURVEY_METHOD" has many values, two of which are "from Plan" and "from Plan*".  When there is no "ST_INTERSECTS" to restrict the search, using either the  "from Plan" or the "from Plan*" search phrase works as expected.  However when an "ST_INTERSECTS" is added to the query and the "from Plan*" search phrase is used the selected markers remain "red".  The attached screen shot is of the failing condition.  I think the asterisk is the problem but have no clue how to make this work.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

[failing condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig3IK.png)

Comment: Why the down vote?  Thanks.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mnpedaler51/o0fr2xn8/34/ that I hope will better explain this bug.